# Is containsString: fast enough to be used to search every time a character is entered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, performance, cocoa-touch

I want to search for substrings (or tokens) in an `NSString` as a user types in a `UITextView`. I want to search for about 12 different substrings, such as "morning", "afternoon", "night", "next monday", "next tuesday", ... "next sunday", "next week", "next month".

My current implementation essentially just uses the `containsString:` selector over and over.

```
if ([text containsString:@"morning"]) {
    // Do something
}

if ([text containsString:@"next monday"]){
    // Do something
} else if ([text containsString:@"next tuesday"]) {
    // Do something
}
```

I've timed my function and it runs in about `.000041` seconds. I run the function each time the user types a character in the `UITextView`. Is there anything I can do to speed up the runtime of the function? And does this runtime even merit optimizing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to speed up the runtime of the function? And does this runtime even merit optimizing?

There is *never* merit in optimizing prematurely. Revisit this issue only as you approach release of your app, and even then only if you actually have a problem (i.e. your app is perceptibly choking on slow code). Until then, move on: don't worry, be happy.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to "do not optimize (yet)"...

How many characters do you write per second? If you do the search 5 times per second, and it totals to 1/1000th of a second, it obviously doesn't matter.

Timing things is a tricky beast though, and results may vary for the current situation. This is obvious for long vs. short input patterns, but testing in a loop might have different characteristics than testing alone.

Possible easy to implement optimizations for later: don't check the whole string each time - just check in the area where the change happened. I'd expect it to be a good improvement - that is, if NSString has an efficient range search. Another approach could be to look for common substrings and eliminate some searches (i.e. in your example, if "next" is not found, the search for "next tuesday" can be skipped).

But mind you - optimization can introduce a ton of bugs, often obscures logic, and - most of all - is often completely useless. :)

Comment: Yep I've thought about some of those suggestions, such as searching for the word next and quitting if it's not found etc. but I definitely agree that these optimizations can often lead to obfuscation of logic